# Discrete integration by parts

Tags: real-analysis, summation

For $k\in K:=\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,N-1\}$, consider the sum
$$
\sum_{k\in K}f_k(g_{k+1}-g_{k-1})
$$
and perform a discrete integration by parts.

---

I am not sure what is meant by discrete integration by parts. I guess this is supposed to mean [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).

We have
$$
\sum_{k\in K}f_k(g_{k+1}-g_{k-1})=\sum_{k\in K}f_k(g_{k+1}-g_k+g_k-g_{k-1})=\underbrace{\sum_{k\in K}f_k(g_{k+1}-g_k)}_{=:A} + \underbrace{\sum_{k\in K}f_k(g_k-g_{k-1})}_{=:B}
$$

For the sum $A$, I can directly apply the formula given in the link:
$$
A=(f_{N-1}g_{N}-f_0g_0)-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}g_k(f_k-f_{k-1}),
$$
Using that $g_N=g_0$ due to the definition of $K$, I therefore get
$$
A=(f_{N-1}g_{0}-f_0g_0)-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}g_k(f_k-f_{k-1}),
$$

Now, I am not sure how to continue with sum $B$. I get
$$
B=(f_0g_0-f_1g_0)-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}g_k(f_{k+1}-f_k)
$$

Comment: I think $K$ should start with $1\,.$ To handle $B$ do this:\begin{align}
B&=\sum_{k=\color{red}1}^{N-1}f_k(g_k-g_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}f_kg_k-f_{k-1}g_{k-1}+f_{k-1}g_{k-1}-f_kg_{k-1}\\
&=f_{N-1}g_{N-1}-f_0g_0-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}g_{k-1}(f_k-f_{k-1})\,.
\end{align}

Comment: I do not think that $K$ starts with $1$.

Comment: What is $g_{k-1}$ when $k=0\,?$ Does not matter. You can work out all the rest. Case closed.

Comment: I think then $g_{-1}=g_{N-1}$

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to think about summation by parts as a discrete analog of integration by parts (as in your question) with differences representing derivatives. In discrete differences, the order of the differencing (approximation of the derivative) is retained. For example, $g_{k+1}-g_{k-1}$ is a second-order difference.

From your derivation, summing $A$ and $B$ gives
$$\sum_{k\in\mathcal{K}}f_k(g_{k+1}-g_{k-1})
=\text{Boundary terms}
-\sum_{k\in\mathcal{K}}g_k(f_{k+1}-f_{k-1}),$$
which is the expected result.